# Android Segmentation Fault

Tags: java, android, segmentation-fault

We are working on a project for Android and our platform is arm-base.
We found that there is very low probability that the application crash happened in dalvik. 
Belows are crash log messages.
I think that segmentation fault is caused by memory corruption, which is root cause of this problems, but I don't know how to debug this issue.

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Regards,

```
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803): *  ** *  ** *  ** *  ** *  ** *
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803): Build fingerprint: 'TI/omap3evm/omap3evm:2.3/GRH55/eng.root.20130321.220023:userdebug/test-keys'
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803): pid: 1229, tid: 1232  >>> com.samsung.xoa.ui.local.android.app.initialsetup <<<
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0063008f
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  r0 00000000  r1 0063006f  r2 40009328  r3 400091e8
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  r4 47095000  r5 40009228  r6 401a06d0  r7 81da5608
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  r8 fffffe7c  r9 81da5608  10 00002000  fp 44dafd78
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  ip 81daad38  sp 44dafd40  lr 81d36348  pc 81d35bd4  cpsr 80000010
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d0  403b0ad0403e6019  d1  40408e704040961a
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d2  4042e4384042eb1b  d3  4042d4d04042dcff
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d4  40258b1840260d48  d5  402393f840252c30
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d6  401f2d8840223d98  d7  40131a50401a8398
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d8  00000011e7adbd96  d9  0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d16 0000000000000000  d17 3ff0000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803):  scr 80000012
06-20 04:42:47.986 I/DEBUG   (  803): 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):          #00  pc 00035bd4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):          #01  pc 00036344  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):          #02  pc 00020338  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): code around pc:
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d35bb4 0a000001 e1a01006 eb014609 e797c008 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d35bc4 e5961000 e59c20ac e1510002 0a0000b5 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d35bd4 e5912020 e3120101 0a000055 e3510000 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d35be4 e1a03001 0a000021 e5950010 e1510000 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d35bf4 3a00001e e5953000 e593c00c e5930010 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): code around lr:
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d36328 e590404c e5812054 e1540003 0a000006 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d36338 e4930004 e1a01007 e5873008 ebfffe10 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d36348 e5973008 e1540003 1afffff8 e3a00000 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d36358 eb0143fe e28dd02c e8bd8ff0 e1a0000b 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 81d36368 eb01442e eafffffa e59fe048 e3a00006 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): 
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): stack:
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd00  400091f0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd04  01040004

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd08  40009228  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd0c  00000000

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd10  00000001

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd14  fffffe7c

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd18  00264fa0  [heap]
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd1c  47095000  /dev/ashmem/CursorWindow (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd20  40009228  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd24  403e8b38  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd28  81da5608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd2c  fffffe7c

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd30  81da5608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd34  00002000

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd38  df002777

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd3c  e3a070ad

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): #00 44dafd40  47095000  /dev/ashmem/CursorWindow (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd44  00253644  [heap]
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd48  00000001

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd4c  40009228  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd50  fffffe7c

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd54  81da5608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd58  00002000

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd5c  81d36348  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803): #01 44dafd60  000002bb

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd64  81d9ef60  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd68  81d9f02c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd6c  81da5608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd70  400091e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd74  fffffe7c

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd78  00253644  [heap]
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd7c  00252b58  [heap]
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd80  00000400

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd84  7fffffff

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd88  400091e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd8c  400091e8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd90  81da5608  /system/lib/libdvm.so
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd94  00000001

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd98  fffffe84

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafd9c  fffffe7c

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafda0  00002710

06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafda4  400091f4  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafda8  400091f8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
06-20 04:42:48.010 I/DEBUG   (  803):     44dafdac 81d2033c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: Try to calculate md5sum of some big file. That usually will return different values if memory is corrupted.

Comment: I tried to calculate md5sum when the error was reproduced, but the md5sum result is not different.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs I could see that you are using Android 2.3 (Gingerbread). actually there is a bug in this version during garbage collection. Thats why I think there is android native library crash.

Please see similar problem here
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/k6rWjsrs_z0

**Work around - (taken from the above link)**:
The work around is to store object array elements atomically.  In the 
Bionic C library, the bcopy routine is implemented separately from 
memmove and, quite fortuitously, moves word sized values atomically. 
This commit switches System.arraycopy to using bcopy instead of 
memmove.